# Delphi 6 PE, как запустить и перевести код

Tags: delphi, компилятор, pe

Прислали исходный код некоторого проекта и сказали, он написан на `Delphi 6 PE`. Сразу с дуру решил попробовать его запустить в `Borland Delphi` и потерпел фиаско. Ошибка, странные конструкции в коде. Поэтому вопрос, как можно запустить код `Delphi 6 PE` в более современных средах? Вижу, что в папке огромное множество `.pas` файлов, значит должно работать, я бы переписал все на новый лад и "новый" `delphi`, но мне оттуда нужно всего пару функций и я бы последовательно убирал все, пока не осталось бы нужное мне. Но для этого нужно тестить, чтобы ничего по пути удаления не сломалось. Может есть какие-то способы автоматического портирования кода? 
Ошибка возникает внутри данной конструкции:

```
(*$DEFINE D1_OR_NEWER *)
       (*$IFNDEF VER80 *)
         (*$DEFINE D2_OR_NEWER *)
         (*$IFNDEF VER90 *)
           (*$DEFINE D3_OR_NEWER *)
           (*$IFNDEF VER100 *)
             (*$DEFINE D4_OR_NEWER *)
             (*$IFNDEF VER120 *)
               (*$DEFINE D5_OR_NEWER *)
               (*$IFNDEF VER130 *)
                 (*$IFDEF LINUX *)
                   (*$DEFINE K1_OR_NEWER *)
                 (*$ENDIF *)
                 (*$IFNDEF VER140 *)
                   If the compiler gets stuck here,
                   you are using a compiler version unknown to this code.
                 (*$ENDIF *)
               (*$ENDIF *)
             (*$ENDIF *)
           (*$ENDIF *)
         (*$ENDIF *)
       (*$ELSE *)
         (*$DEFINE WIN16 *)
       (*$ENDIF *)
```

Понятно, что нет поддержки, но сейчас таких компиляторов почти не достать, все ссылки которые я видел уже лет 10 как закрыты.

Comment: В какой версии Delphi Вы это пытаетесь скомпилировать?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, Delphi 7

Comment: Delphi7 - это не `современная среда` Она была выпущена в 2002 году. 16 лет назад. Через год после Delphi6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Delphi 7 определена константа `VER150` У Вас заканчивается перебор на `VER140`. Допишите условие

```
(*$IFNDEF VER130 *)
  (*$IFDEF LINUX *)
    (*$DEFINE K1_OR_NEWER *)
  (*$ENDIF *)
  (*$IFNDEF VER140 *)
    (*$DEFINE D6_OR_NEWER *)
    (*$IFNDEF VER150 *)
      If the compiler gets stuck here,
      you are using a compiler version unknown to this code.
    (*$ENDIF *)
  (*$ENDIF *)
(*$ENDIF *)
```

И посмотрите, что получится

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Только я бы вместо `(*$DEFINE D6_OR_NEWER *)` прописал `(*$DEFINE D5_OR_NEWER *)`, т.к. чужой код про "D6_OR_NEWER" ничего не знает...

Comment: @Alekcvp `$DEFINE D5_OR_NEWER` пропишется в любом случае, а `$DEFINE D6_OR_NEWER` понадобится, если всплывут особенности, D7 несовместимые с D6